# It possible to change the ion-range orientation using ionic2/3?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2, ionic3

It possible to change the ion-range orientation using ionic2/3?
I'm trying to change the ion-range orientation using the ionic2/3.

I changed the ion-range using the css transform:

```
<ion-label>Range</ion-label>     
<ion-range min="1000" max="2000" step="100" snaps="true" color="secondary"></ion-range>

  ion-range {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

Visually that is work but if i need to change the ion-range value still I need to slide horizontally.

So how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution yet from Ionic team regarding this. This issue was discussed on ionic team github and it is in [their feature request backlog now but no commitment yet to implement](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6019).